# Select query from Master when Using TypeOrm with NestJs

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, pg, master-slave, nestjs-typeorm

---

**SETUP INFO**

---

Before moving to actual problem let me explain you the Architectural Setup. So we have a **Postgres Cluster** with **Master and Slave Configuration**. In this cluster, we have used the **Synchronous Replication Strategy** with **sychronous_commit** as **remote_apply**.

For ref: https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/08/21/postgresql-synchronous_commit-options-and-synchronous-standby-replication/

---

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

---

We are using TypeOrm with NestJs (not going in details how the modules are instantiated and how the connection is happening, please consider that it is happening and we are able to get the data via the Connections created by TypeOrm).

We have exposed certain functions to talk to tables via TypeOrm API.

The issue is that when we hit a select query on any table, it automatically, tries to get it from the **SLAVE** of the Postgres Cluster.

---

**QUERY**

---

Is there any **Typeorm api option** available via which we can tell TypeOrm, that for the specific call **please don't go to slave rather go to master** for its execution.

Today we are using something like this:

```
    /**
      PLEASE CONSIDER ALL IMPORTS AND CONFIGS WORKING PERFECTLY FINE FOR NESTJS
    */
    export class SomeClassName {
        constructor(@InjectRepository(ENTITYNAME) private readonly entityRepository: Repository<Entity>) {}

        /**
         *
         * @description this function finds the record from the db and return it
         * @param id the record that needs to be returned
         */
        async findSomething(id: string): Promise<Entity> {
            /**
             * This call is going to PG Cluster Slave since its a SELECT call (behind the scenes).
             * What we want, is for this call, we will pass any FLAG or ANY config,
             * that forces TYPEORM to get this specific data from MASTER
             */
            return this.entityRepository.findOne({ job_id: id });
        }
    }
```

---

If not possible with Repository pattern, is there any other way, via which we can tell Typeorm to get the data from the Master?

Please shed some views. Happy Coding :)

Comment: This may help https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/multiple-data-sources.md#replication

Comment: Looks, like we need the same, but would have been good if given via Repo Pattern. But anyways, thanks for the help. Let me check the same.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to inject EntityManager and create a query runner specifying the database

```
const queryRunner = this.entityManager.connection.createQueryRunner('master')
```

and then use

```
queryRunner.manager(Entity, query)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution is to configure in you typeorm MASTER and SLAVE servers for databases
Something like this should work for you

All inserts will happen via master and read will be redirected evenly between slaves

```
function getOptions(): DataSourceOptions {
    const type = 'postgres';
    const logging = process.env.DB_LOGGING === 'true';
    const synchronize = process.env.DB_SYNCHRONIZE === 'true';
    const entities = [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', '**', 'entities/*{index.ts,.entity.ts,.entity.js}')];
    const migrations = [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'database', 'migrations/*{.ts,.js}')];
    const migrationsRun = process.env.DB_MIGRATIONS_RUN === 'true';

    if (process.env.DB_REPLICATION === 'true') {
        const master = {
            host: process.env.DB_HOST_MASTER,
            port: Number.parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT_MASTER ?? '', 10),
            username: process.env.DB_USERNAME_MASTER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD_MASTER,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME_MASTER
        };

        const slaves: PostgresConnectionCredentialsOptions[] = [];

        for (let i = 0; ; i++) {
            if (process.env[`DB_HOST_SLAVE_${i}`]) {
                slaves.push({
                    host: process.env[`DB_HOST_SLAVE_${i}`],
                    port: Number.parseInt(process.env[`DB_PORT_SLAVE_${i}`] ?? '', 10),
                    username: process.env[`DB_USERNAME_SLAVE_${i}`],
                    password: process.env[`DB_PASSWORD_SLAVE_${i}`],
                    database: process.env[`DB_NAME_SLAVE_${i}`]
                });
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return {
            type,
            replication: {
                master,
                slaves
            },
            logging,
            synchronize,
            entities,
            migrations,
            migrationsRun
        };
    } else {
        return {
            type,
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: Number.parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT ?? '', 10),
            username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
            password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            logging,
            synchronize,
            entities,
            migrations,
            migrationsRun
        };
    }
}
```